# Opencv HoughLines Lines Theta?

Tags: c++, opencv, lines, hough-transform

I have a question about opencv libary of HoughLines. The format is below from the official website:

C++: void HoughLines(InputArray image, OutputArray lines, double rho, double theta, int threshold, double srn=0, double stn=0 )

And the explanation of output array parameter of lines, it says:

lines – Output vector of lines. Each line is represented by a two-element vector: rho and theta. and theta is 0 for vertical lines and pi/2 for horizontal lines(in radiance).

I'm wondering what's the principle of theta? It seems that theta is in the range of 0~1.57 (since pi/2 is 1.57), but I run the code and find out that theta can exceed 1.57 and become some strange value, like the figure below, red line is the detected line by HoughLines, and sita is the value in parameter lines?
[image].

Can anyone tell me what's regularity of theta that output from lines?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The angle seems correct, counting from X axis counterclockwise, or from Y axis clockwise.

Comment: So you mean the opposite line may have same theta?

Comment: Theta is not bound to the interval [0,PI/2], it just indicates the direction in which the angle is measured. 
As @AlexanderEkzhanov said, the angle is measured counter-clockwise, starting from the x-axis, which gives you a value of PI/2 for vertical lines. It doesn't mean that Theta can not exceed this value.

Comment: The x-axis means the top side of the image right? or is the Cartiesin coordinate x-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I understood. The angle which I thought your console should show is Orange one (about -0.72 rad). But seems like OpenCV uses positive angle for all parallel lines to your line. I mean purple angle which is what your console shows (about 2.5 rad). So your line has this theta and rho (distance to line) is negative value. This is because your line lies on the right side of the origin. (I drew picture in Paint, sorry if it is not pretty)

[image]

Comment: So it seems like opencv lines can not tell the direction of the line right?

Comment: I am not sure about all opencv lines, @HenryChen. In this particular case theta doesn't show angle of the line. It shows the angle between x-axis and perpendicular to the line in clockwise direction.

Comment: So you mean what my console show is the purple one, no matter rho and theta is the purple one?

Comment: Im not quiet understand your point sorry, but why not it just show the orange one? Isn't the orange's angel is also positive?

Comment: @HenryChen, No, orange angle is negative since it is on the counter-clockwise direction from x-axis. That's why OpenCV uses parallel line which lies on the left side of the origin and gives positive angle in clockwise direction. Using purple angle is OK since position of your line will be adjusted by negative rho value (it means your line will be in the right side). Does it make sense to you?

Comment: @Kanat your answer makes sense, but it doesn't change the fact that the docs are wrong for this function.  You are saying (and I agree, having seen the same result as the OP), that the 'distance' can be negative and the angle does not lie in [0, pi/2].

Answer (score 8):

The docs for OpenCV, the other answer to this question, and wikipedia (as of writing this answer) are wrong.  Its the first time in my life I have found a technical error in wikipedia.

cv2.HoughLines gives you pairs (r, theta) that map to lines.  Theta is the counter clockwise angle between the x axis (of the image) and the line.  It is between zero and pi.  Rho is the "distance" from the upper left of the image to the line.  As the OP points out, rho is often negative and thus not a proper distance.  Here is what the authors of OpenCV meant:

If theta < pi/2, we are talking about a line that goes from the bottom left of the image to the top right.  In this case, it cannot cross the x axis below 0, and we know exactly the line to draw (given rho).  Up to this point the OpenCV docs are right.

If theta > pi/2, then we need to disambiguate between the two parallel lines that are equidistant from the origin.  To deal with this, the authors of HoughLines made a rule: **if theta > pi/2, lines that pass through the left side of the image have positive rho and lines that go through the top of the image have negative rho.**

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by "As the OP points out"? What is OP? Sorry if my question sounds too dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Rho is the size of the 'bucket' or accumulator array for all incoming rho, or distance from origin.  The longest possible distance in an image is from the top left to bottom right, so for maximum accuracy, plug that value into houghlines rho.
Theta is the size of the bucket for all incoming theta.  For maximum accuracy you need a value of 180.  To only detect even angles, theta should be 90.  to only detect angles divisible by 30, theta should be 6